# machine learning Positive definite matrix

Tags: matrix, artificial-intelligence

what are the necessary conditions for a positive definite matrix ?
I know that all the eigenvalues should be positive but what else ?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing else. A matrix *A* in *V* is defined to be positive definite if *x<sup>T</sup>Ax>0* for all vectors *x∊V∖{0}*. This is equivalent to the definition that all eigenvectors of *A* are positive (and therefore in ℝ).

By the way: questions like these should better be put on https://math.stackexchange.com/